Dependency injection - passing responsibility for dependency to a Client?
I have long standing argue about dependency injection and SOLID principles with my teammate. We both want to make an Exporter, to export data into various formats.
My approach (in PHP):
class Exporter {
  public function __construct(private WriterContract $writer) 
  {
  }

  public function export(): void {
    // Do stuff and assign to $data
    $this->writer->write($data);
  }
}

class ExportController {
  public function __construct(private Exporter $exporter) {
  }

  public function route(Request $request): Response {
    $this->exporter->export();

    return Response(200, ['success!'])
  }
}

Teammates approach:
class Exporter {
  public function __construct(private WriterContract $writer) 
  {
  }

  public function export(): Data {
    // Do stuff and assign to $data
    return $data;
  }
}

class ExportController {
  public function __construct(private Exporter $exporter, private WriterContract $writer) {
  }

  public function route(Request $request): Response {
    $data = $this->exporter->export();
    $this->writer->write($data);

    return Response(200, ['success!'])
  }
}

I think none of approaches is really bad, they just have different pros and cons.
My approach is easier to use for a client, but adds extra dependency to the Exporter class.
Teammates approach doesn't add extra dependency, but next developer who comes after my teammate needs to better know how to use it, because writer is now his responsibility. And Writer dependency is in fact only moved to a Client, so I don't see a real benefit here.
What do you think? Is any of these two approaches cleaner or objectively better? Am I missing any other approach?

Structurally, your approach in general makes proper testing easier (each class deals with a specific part of the overall problem, makes fewer assumptions, and each needs just one mock). That said, it's not necessarily a bad idea to have something that's more like a data transformer or, as Ewan suggested, a converter (that just produces the output data structure), and do the actual write elsewhere - I guess this is what your teammate was thinking. You guys are going to have to discuss it and decide what to do (and perhaps arrive at a third option).

They are both terrible! First off PHP..... ..and don't get me started on space indentation!...
Jokes aside. I think what you are missing is a Converter class and some read and write classes.
eg
public class Exporter //NEW LINE!!
{
  public bool Export(id)
  {
     inData = this.InRepository.Read(id);
     outData = this.Converter.Convert(inData);
     this.OutRepository.Write(id,outData);
  }
}

Now each separate bit of logic has its own class and you can orchestrate them in the Exporter class, OR if you are happy with fat controllers, which I think in this case is totally acceptable, in a controller method.

Psssh. You C# folks and your newlines before every curly brace.

Oh noes, I was expecting some microsoftwannabealmostjava dude the tab kingdom! Thanks, this post made me laugh!
Both Repository and Convertor (which I assume would be something to hydrate records) are not mentioned as they were not important for the given question.
Thanks for pointing me to a NEW LINE!!!

@JohnyProkie "[Repository and Converter not mentioned] as they were not important for the given question" - perhaps not directly, but, as you presented it, your teammate's "Exporter" is actually a converter like the one Ewan described, so it might be important to clear this up when discussing it with your teammate. In a way, each of you basically arrived to a solution that's part way to this one, approaching it from different directions.

New line is the important thing. Having all the dependencies in the same layer rather than nested is just a secondary issue for nerds to argue about!

This all depends on how tightly coupled the data structure is to the export format. If you cannot use the same data structure to export to different formats, then there is no point in separating this logic. For example, if you need to export to a spreadsheet or an XML file, and both export formats need different data structures, just keep all the logic in one class. Separating the logic for reading, transforming and exporting data only makes sense when you can substitute any of the readers, writers and transformers without affecting the data structures passed between the components.
